# ODE system: change 't' to get a linear and autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following ode system is given where $a\in\mathbb R$ is an unknown parameter
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}=(t^2+1)(ax+3y)\\
&\frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t}=(t^2+1)((a+2)x+y)
\end{align*}
I'm asked to find a time parametrization s=h(t) to turn the ode system into an autonomous linear system but i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce $s = h(t) = \dfrac{t^3}{3} + t$. Then by the chain rule $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{ds}(t^2+1) = (t^2+1)(ax + 3y),$$ from which it follows that $$\dfrac{dx}{ds} = ax + 3y.$$ The same time re-parameterization will lead to $$\dfrac{dy}{ds} = (a+2)x + y,$$ and the system is now autonomous with respect to the parameter $s$. It should be observed that the function $h$ is one-to-one for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, with inverse $$t = 2\sinh{\left[\frac{1}{3}\sinh^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3s}{2}\right)\right]}.$$